# Gesture support for WPF WebBrowser Control which is displaying a HTML5 Site

Tags: wpf, touch, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-10

In a standard WPF app, I have a WebBrowser control which has been navigated to a HTML5 sample page (http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/BrowserSurface/).

In the browser outside the app, I can interact with this site as expected – move photo’s around, use gestures etc.

In the WebBrowser control the site does not work as expected. It renders, but it does not respond to any touch gestures – It will, however, zoom in and out when I pinch.

Is it possible to make the WebBrowser control pass gesture events etc so that I can interact with the site as I would in a normal browser?

Many thanks for any help with this!

Kris

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I think this has something to do with the fact that the WebBrowserControl standard uses IE7 ActiveX. I had the same problem which always gave me JavaScript errors in the control for TouchEvents.
After I added some registery key to force the WebBrowserControl to use the latest IE version installed it worked.

Here is what I've add to my registery. Paste it in a txt file and save it as an .reg file. Then DoubleClick it. Or enter the key/value manual in your registery via Regedit.
I even included this in my application code to add the key/value automaticially if it doesn't exist yet.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
```

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"RetailTestApplication.exe"=dword:270f

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"RetailTestApplication.exe"=dword:270f

Sorry, the code plugin srews up.

[Change IE version for the WPF WebBrowserControl](http://stievens-corner.be/index.php/10-wpf/37-change-ie-version-for-the-wpf-webbrowsercontrol)

[MSDN Internet Feature Controls (B..C)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)